# How to Upload a file to Sharepoint - problem with login and password

Tags: development, file-upload

For my WPF program I have followed [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4baa9152-8e11-410f-934a-78d9119f970f/c-wpf-how-to-download-and-upload-file-from-sharepoint-teamsite-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopment) example. Everything seems working fine but in the end I get this error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 'The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.'

Perhaps I might have gone wrong because I slightly changed my code as below

```
string siteUrl = @"https://hexmet.sharepoint.com/sites/HMIEMEA/Italy/Projects/project_99/Lists/test%201";  <---this my company sharepoint sites

var login = <------------here my email
var password = <---------here the pwd I use to log on my computer

ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

Web web = context.Web;
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\temp\\A.txt");//("c:\\temp\\result.json");

//file url is name
newFile.Url = @"A.txt";// @"result.json";
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Files");

//get folder and add to that
Folder folder = docs.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("result");
File uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(newFile);

context.Load(docs);
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();<-----here the error
```

On the execute query this error

[image]

so it seems that login and pwd are not correct. But I really do not know what else to put in here.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438039/c-how-to-download-and-upload-file-from-sharepoint-teamsite-site) didn't help...

Thanks for any help

---ADD---
Could it be that I have splitted uncorrectly the site url?
When I use the browser it is

https://hexmet.sharepoint.com/sites/HMIEMEA/Italy/Projects/project_99/SitePages/Home.aspx?e=1%3A3da8d3a60b5c464c823027fa22113fb5

please take a look at how I have splitted it above. Thanks

Comment: Does the password have any special characters in it that may be escaped by C#?

Comment: Not at all! My login is like name.surname@company.com while my pwd is like NameNumberNameNumber. Please take a look at my add above

Comment: The URL you included at the bottom of your question is the URL to the home page of the site. The URL for the site itself is just https://hexmet.sharepoint.com/sites/HMIEMEA/Italy/Projects/project_99. However, use of the incorrect site URL should give an error message that starts with "There is no Web named...", not an error message that indicates an incorrect username or password.